# Specifying Language for a grammar

Tags: computer-science, grammar

Is there any specific methodology followed to specify a language for given grammar ?? i.e. Is it necessary to run all the production rules given in a grammar to determine the language it represents? I don't have an example as such since the one I am working on is a homework question.

```
[edit]: adding an example, Describe, in English, the language defined by the grammar

    <S> -> <A> <B> <C>
         <A> -> a <A> | a
         <B> -> b <B> | b
         <C> -> c <C> | c
```

Regards,

darkie15

Comment: Define what you mean by 'specify'. Normally the grammar itself is considered a specification for the language.

Comment: You might want to consult the [Tree Automata Techniques and Applications](http://tata.gforge.inria.fr/) book, especially chapter 1 and 2.4. Download is free, and it provides a good approach from a theoretical point of view.

Comment: "Guess" the language that the grammar defines, and then prove to yourself (or your professor) using induction that your guess is correct.

Comment: Does not help !! Hoping for better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you example, the part

```
<A> -> <A> a | a
```

recognizes exactly non empty lists of `a`
The same goes for the two other productions, `<B>` and `<C>`, with respectively `b` and `c`.

Thus, with `<S> -> <A> <B> <C>`, you deduce that the language this grammar recognizes is any non empty list of `a`, followed by a non empty list of `b`, then a non empty list of `c`, corresponding to the regular expression `a+b+c+`.

Proof is quite easy from there to show that each instance recognized by the regular expression is recognized by the grammar, using induction.